# Numpy Calculating the distance of elements with each other

Tags: python, numpy

Basically, I have a 4x4096 complex matrix, and I want to calculate the distance of each column with another elements in the matrix. I already have a working piece of code

```
import numpy as np
data = np.random.rand(4,4096)
norms = []
for i in range(4096):
     for j in range(i,4096):
         norms.append(np.linalg.norm(data[:,i]-data[:,j]))
print(min(norms))
```

Above is an example code but explains what I am trying to achieve, my problem is this has a time complexity of O(N^2) and since the array is quite large it runs slower than what i want. Is there any "numpy magic" that can make the whole process faster?

Comment: That's not the norm "with each other", it's the norm of the difference, a.k.a the distance.

Comment: Yes you are right, changed the wording thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
norms = np.fill_diagonal(
  np.linalg.norm(data[:, np.newaxis, :] - data[:, :, np.newaxis], axis=0),
  np.inf
)
```

It runs quite fast for me:

```
CPU times: user 315 ms, sys: 477 ms, total: 793 ms
Wall time: 800 ms
```

Running your original code takes a while longer:

```
CPU times: user 1min 1s, sys: 4.59 s, total: 1min 6s
Wall time: 1min 2s
```

But it's probably a good idea to use a package:

```py
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist
min_norm = pdist(data.T).min()
```

Comment: your `norms` differ from the OP's `norms`. You also need to add `.ravel()` at the end to get the shape from the question. Eventually, the OP's `len(norms)`  is `8390656`, yours `norms.ravel().size` is `16777216`

Comment: It doesn't matter, in this case each distance appears twice, once on both sides of the diagonal. In practice, this should be done directly with scipy.

Comment: You may be able to approx. halve execution time by using `np.triu_indices` or `np.tril_indices`.